# No content visible after upgrade to Polymer 2.0

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-2.x

I have a page with an inline element which does not show anything anymore since I upgraded to Polymer 2.0. Not even the two `<p>` tags with *Hello* and *World* are showing...

All the elements have also been upgraded to the latest version.

What could be the problem? Following is the simplified code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
<title>App</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<link rel="icon" href="/resources/img/app_icon_no_text_big_trans-9ba078a979d5a6f438b108982a5fbc96.png" />
<script src="/resources/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite-b591b76678e2f5d584eff169fd0ff2f8.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/style-081a2143eab1562ed0f2571c8a69aa2c.css" />
<link rel="import" href="/resources/bower_components/polymer/lib/utils/path-b668241452b073a2fea7a9da33eb822f.html" />
<link rel="import" href="/resources/bower_components/polymer/polymer-ff2cd4c34828a0ffe4677bf933618de4.html" />
<link rel="import" href="/resources/bower_components/neon-animation/web-animations-577638b27a2a77c751047a7b77cb49f2.html" />
<link rel="import" href="/resources/bower_components/iron-media-query/iron-media-query-68909d114753991b22e832a46c779989.html" />
<link rel="import" href="/resources/bower_components/paper-button/paper-button-72d61e146e55153140612cba12c5a0d2.html" />
<link rel="import" href="/resources/bower_components/paper-scroll-header-panel/paper-scroll-header-panel-4e1b613ae79a795c438f204034e2359c.html" />
<link rel="import" href="/resources/bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar-392c19c3b918829cfe607f5f06be2b9e.html" />
<link rel="import" href="/resources/bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout-classes-c4cb7663a6214c0ad5c41729bfef2a3d.html" />
<link rel="import" href="/resources/bower_components/paper-styles/paper-styles-b8ddb70e55605c10e863482164aaaf33.html" />
<link rel="import" href="/resources/bower_components/paper-input/paper-textarea-fc7a0e4378c4bbdb90def32c59e72e2f.html" />
<link rel="import" href="/resources/bower_components/paper-checkbox/paper-checkbox-4d9b1ae1de7400ef96ae83fc9d618091.html" />
<link rel="import" href="/resources/bower_components/paper-radio-group/paper-radio-group-ad71ba718a01c94ffa76055946ade51a.html" />
<link rel="import" href="/resources/bower_components/paper-dialog/paper-dialog-f2aefeaf573e039ecdca774350244730.html" />
<link rel="import" href="/resources/bower_components/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu-cdd5e16fb048b585c2a4839591761617.html" />
<link rel="import" href="/resources/bower_components/paper-menu/paper-menu-ba00de0ca049d5c92e997c9f7c97d249.html" />
<link rel="import" href="/resources/bower_components/paper-item/paper-item-5439bb441f5b1d110a7e248595b05b38.html" />
<link rel="import" href="/resources/bower_components/paper-toast/paper-toast-36788cb33654ce8cdcd83b8a9805605f.html" />
<link rel="import" href="/resources/bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button-8d30ba3b103e167984f97820112f4a4b.html" />
<link rel="import" href="/resources/bower_components/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu-cdd5e16fb048b585c2a4839591761617.html" />
<link rel="import" href="/resources/bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons-b2c3dcd68233e5e47f103df8ad3dc005.html" />
<link rel="import" href="/resources/bower_components/neon-animation/neon-animated-pages-efbf9e097eb34d2e2ae1d705cf8d0ca9.html" />
<link rel="import" href="/resources/bower_components/neon-animation/neon-animatable-cde611461ee6da675070fe79744df5b8.html" />
<link rel="import" href="/resources/bower_components/neon-animation/neon-animations-a0171c87c0fe88bdd8e270f1d1f39534.html" />
<link rel="import" href="/resources/bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax-8a5a2954627628d15c9b743eaedb9ac1.html" />
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <dom-module id="app-home">
        <template>
            <style include="iron-flex iron-flex-factors iron-flex-reverse iron-positioning iron-flex-alignment"></style>
            <custom-style>
            <style is="custom-style">
                paper-scroll-header-panel {
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
                }
            </style>
            </custom-style>
            <paper-scroll-header-panel fixed>
                <paper-toolbar>
                    <paper-button on-tap="clickIntro">À propos</paper-button>
                    <paper-button on-tap="clickSignUp">Inscription</paper-button>
                    <paper-button on-tap="clickLogIn">Connexion</paper-button>
                    <span class="flex"></span>
                    <paper-menu-button vertical-align="top" horizontal-align="right" vertical-offset="72">
                        <paper-icon-button icon="icons:language" class="dropdown-trigger" alt="menu"></paper-icon-button>
                        <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
                            <paper-item on-tap="loadUrl" data-url="/home?lang=de">Deutsch</paper-item>
                            <paper-item on-tap="loadUrl" data-url="/home?lang=en">English</paper-item>
                            <paper-item on-tap="loadUrl" data-url="/home?lang=fr">Français</paper-item>
                            <paper-item on-tap="loadUrl" data-url="/home?lang=ru">Русский</paper-item>
                        </paper-menu>
                    </paper-menu-button>
                </paper-toolbar>
                <neon-animated-pages selected="[[selected]]" entry-animation="[[entryAnimation]]" exit-animation="[[exitAnimation]]">
                    <neon-animatable>
                        <div>Content 1</div>
                    </neon-animatable>
                    <neon-animatable>
                        <div>Content 2</div>
                    </neon-animatable>
                    <neon-animatable>
                        <div>Content 3</div>
                    </neon-animatable>
                </neon-animated-pages>
            </paper-scroll-header-panel>
        </template>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {

                Polymer({
                    is : "app-home",
                    behaviors : [ Polymer.NeonAnimationRunnerBehavior ],
                    properties : {
                        selected : {
                            type : Number,
                            value : 0
                        },
                        user : {
                            type : Object,
                            value : {}
                        },
                        account : {
                            type : Object,
                            value : {
                                address : {}
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    ready : function(e) {}
                });
            });
        </script>
    </dom-module>
    <app-home></app-home>
    <p>World</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit**

It turns out the problem is `<paper-scroll-header-panel>`, which I am aware of that it's deprecated, but I still expected it wo work...

I changed the element to use `<app-layout>` and now it works better. The animations seem to be non-working, but that's not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

From Polymer v2 [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/about_20):

> Polymer 2.0 uses standard ES6 classes and the standard custom elements
>   v1 methods for defining elements, instead of a Polymer factory method.

Your app component is not defined correctly for Polymer v2. See a basic example [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements#main-document-definitions).

Then you have to define properties, behaviors and functions correctly. See the documentation linked, everything is explained there.

Comment: that's not true. He can still use Hybrid elements in Polymer 2.x. So the structure remains almost same but only few things need to be changed.
More info: https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/hybrid-elements